# For all elements in dataframe, count number of like and unlike elements by group factor

Tags: r

I am attempting to count the number of like and unlike neighbors within groups from a dataframe in R, but I want the results to be in relation to all individual elements in the original dataframe. My starting dataframe looks something like this:

```
Group  ID
1      A
1      A
1      B
2      A
2      B
3      C
```

And I want to return two vectors that looks like this:

```
Same  Different
1     1
1     1
0     2
0     1
0     1
0     0
```

I can easily do this using a loop and some simple subsetting, or by using tapply and table together and then merging the results based on sample ID with the orignal dataframe. However, I know there is a simpler way to do this. My impression is there a way to accomplish this using apply functions, but I am having trouble figuring out how to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain the logic of your output?

Comment: For example, for row one, the item ID is A, which is found in group 1. There is one additional item A in group 1 (on row 2), and one item B (row 3). Hence, for row one, there is one same and one different items.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using some standard `R` functions. We use `by` to "split" the data by `Group`, the we iterate over individual values of `ID` using the `sapply` function. The rest of the code is stacking the results back together.

```
cbind(dat, 
      do.call('rbind', 
              by(dat, dat$Group, function(d) 
                  t(sapply(d$ID, 
                           function(x) c('same' = sum(x == d$ID) - 1, 
                                         'different' = sum(x != d$ID)))))))

  Group ID same different
1     1  A    1         1
2     1  A    1         1
3     1  B    0         2
4     2  A    0         1
5     2  B    0         1
6     3  C    0         0
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), ID = c("A", 
"A", "B", "A", "B", "C")), .Names = c("Group", "ID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Great thank you! The by function is what I was missing. Appreciate it.

Comment: I am glad it helped you. You may consider accepting and upvoting my solution if it solved your problem.